# Extracting Active Directory records using SSIS and SQL

Tags: t-sql, ssis, active-directory

I am trying to extract data from Active Directory and also maintain a regular delta load weekly.

What have I done?

I have loaded the initial load with help of Active Directory team using a `.csv` file as we know that Active Directory only has 1000 record load limit while using it in SSIS.

Now that we have an initial load already in the target table can we use some delta method to extract only updated active directory records using SSIS because now the delta record count wont be 1000 for sure it will be like 10 or 100 max and hence my SSIS will run.

My SSIS source query is like :

```
SELECT 
    ipPhone, whenChanged, whenCreated, manager, company,
    department, title, telephoneNumber, physicalDeliveryOfficeName,
    displayName, mail, SN, givenName, employeeID  
FROM 
    'LDAP://BHC-ADDCP01.bayshore.ca/DC=bayshore,DC=ca' 
WHERE 
    objectClass = 'User'
```

The target table already has initial full 15k records of all employees.

How and where do I write a delta kind of query to only get updated records in target table keeping in note that the columns above are object datatype and 1 important columns I feel is `whenChanged` which can tell me when did anyone change their record in Active Directory.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need If there is already a entry in the destination table and a new entry is made into the source table, the SSIS package should only insert the new record into the destination table. It should not insert duplicate records in the destination table

#### Use of Lookup Transformation in SSIS

The Lookup Transformation in SSIS is a powerful and useful SSIS transformation to compare the source and destination data. It filters out the matched and unmatched data in the specified destinations.

The source table gets a new entry in the [dbo].[AADuserDetails] table. In the following table, we inserted 3 new rows

[image]

The destination table contains the previous 3 rows. Now, once we execute the SSIS package, it should only insert last 3 rows  in the destination table.

[image]

#### Create an SSIS package for Lookup Transformation in SSIS

Use the following steps to create an SSIS package.

- Open SQL Server Data Tools and create a new integration project
- Drag a Data Flow Task from the SSIS toolbox to the Control Flow

  [image: SSIS]
- Right-click on Data Flow Task and rename it to SSIS LOOKUP TRANSFORMATION (as your requirement)
- Double click on this task, and it moves to the Data Flow tab

[image]

Drag an OLE DB Source **(or a Flat File Source if you have data in .CSV)** in Data Flow Task and configure it to provide the OLE DB connection manager and name of the table or view, in our case, it is table [AADuserDetails].

[image]

Now, add a Lookup task in the control flow and join the  **OLE DB Source**  task with this Lookup task using a arrow.

[image]

To configure the Lookup task, double click on it, and it opens the following  **Lookup Transformation Editor.**

In  **Lookup Transformation Editor,**  We specify the connection manager and cache type. These details are outside the scope of this article and for now we will go with the default values of these.

[image]

In the drop-down of  **Specify how to handle rows with no matching entries,** select the following option

- Redirect rows to no match output

We want the rows from source to destination table only if the destination table does not have it already. This **Redirect rows to no match output** compare both the tables and if it finds any difference then only it forwards the rows to the destination table.

Click on Connections and specify the **destination table** from the drop-down. I have both the source and destination tables in the same database. You can create a separate connection here as well.

[image]

Click on the Columns, and it shows the source and destination table. We want to compare the **user_id** columns on both tables. Drag on the **user_id** column from the source and move it to the destination **user_id** column. It draws an arrow, as shown in the following image.

[image]

Add an OLE DB destination from the SSIS Toolbox. Join the Lookup task with the OLE DB destination, and it opens the following Input-Output selection.

Select the following values.

- **Output:**  Lookup No Match Output
- **Input:**  OLE DB Destination Input

[image]

Click OK and configure the destination table in the OLE DB Destination.

Look at the arrow between Lookup and destination, and it shows  **Looking No Match Output**.

[image]

At this point, we have 6 rows  in the source table, but it is not completely available in the destination table.

[image]

Let’s run the package, click on START to execute the package

- The source table has 6 rows
- Lookup transformation checks both tables and finds a new record in the destination, and it only inserts the new record in the destination table.

we can see that it transferred 6 rows from the source to the destination because the destination table had 3 rows before the package execution.

[image]

It transferred all unmatched rows (3 rows) to the destination table.

[image]